# Find neo4j node details having just one Edge

Tags: neo4j

I have a database of two types of nodes : users and events connected with relationship DOES.
What would be the cypher to find those users who did only one event ?
I want to find User nodes with only one edge ?

Answer (score 2):

This might be faster than Stefans suggestion, as it uses the node-degree internally.

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE size((u)-[:DOES]->()) = 1
RETURN u
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:DOES]->()
WITH u, count(*) as count
WHERE count = 1
RETURN u
```